# How to verify that $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I've been verifying which functions are analytic and where they are, using the Cauchy Riemann condition, so I need to separate the functions into $u$ and $v$ parts, but how to do it for the following funciton:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}e^{\frac{1}{z}}$$

?

Comment: Do you have to do it with Cauchy-Riemann?  There are much easier ways.

Comment: @David which way? Maybe I can, I don't know

Comment: @user371177 if f(x) is analytic and g(x) is analytic, and g(x)!=0, then f(x)/g(x) is analytic.

Comment: BTW I should have said there are much easier ways **sometimes** :)

Answer (score 1):

Use two results about combinations of analytic functions.

> (1) If $f$ is analytic at $a$ and $g$ is analytic at $f(a)$, then $g\circ f$ is analytic at $a$.
>
> (2) If $f$ and $g$ are analytic at $a$ and $g(a)\ne0$, then $f/g$ is analytic at $a$.

By (2) or general knowledge, $1/z$ is analytic everywhere except $0$.

Also $e^z$ is analytic everywhere, so by (1), $e^{1/z}$ is analytic everywhere except $0$.

By (2), $\dfrac{e^{1/z}}{1-z}$ is analytic everywhere except $z=0,1$.